# In GWT server-side code I want to interact with interface

Tags: gwt, user-interface, user-experience, jsni

I want to know if it's possible and how it will be possible, in server-side to interact with backend interface?

In a server-side method I am executing severals queries, afetr each queries results I want to change the progressbar displayed in my interface (in order to add good UX feedback for the user).
The problem is in server-side code i can't call JSNI method in order to do this:

```
 // call query 1 and return results
 $doc.getElementById("myProgressBar").style.width='30%';
 // call query 2 and return results
 $doc.getElementById("myProgressBar").style.width='50%';
 // call query 3 and return results
 $doc.getElementById("myProgressBar").style.width='70%';
 //...
```

So what will be the good way in server-side to interact with the interface? (and tell me it's possible thanks J)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot, there could be many "interfaces" (clients), how could you identify which client is doing what? See [Client-Server Architecture/Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model) to get an understanding.

Back to your question, what I would do is to write the progress bar value in the http session and use [GWT-RPC](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) to poll (say every 5 seconds) the server asking for it, until you get to 100 or get an exception. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902146/how-to-implement-progressbar-with-gwt), should help you out.